# ToolTipService in UWP is crash when using listview

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, tooltip

[image]

when firstly I click to Image It's so OK show listview but secondly click It's has been crashed.

Firstly Click Image:

[image]

Secondly Click Image:

[image]

Comment: Hi, please copy-paste your code block in the first image to the question. Images are used to show the problem, we need the code to reproduce the issue, and we cannot copy the code from an image.

Comment: Would also be helpful to see whatever error info you get, certainly there's some sort of stacktrace or something.